# Javascript link autoembedding with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have some troubles with this regular expression in javascript. That same regex works in PHP, but in JavaScript this error occurs: *"Invalid regular expression: unrecognized character after (?"*. My regular expression is:

```js
text = text.replace(/(?<!\=\")http([A-Za-z0-9:\/\.\+\?\%\@\!\#\&_-]+)/g,
    '<a href="http$1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http$1</a> ');
```

The problem is in first part (`?< !\=\"`) but I don't know how to solve it because it is a normal regular expression for PHP or C.

Is there any analog of this construction? I need to disallow symbol `"` (double quotes) right before "http" for preventing url replacements in html elements like `<img>`.

I'm edit the question because the symbols `<` plus `!` make an error in displaying text after it. (that, may also invoke error).

Comment: Not totally tracking with what you're saying. I do see the above that you're using, please edit or comment to give an example of what you're starting with and what you'd like to end up with.

Comment: @Peter ok, what i have: text = 'something bla bla bla like this http://domain.com/blabla/bla.php or more.' What i want is to change that url to : text = 'something bla bla bla like this <a href="http://domain.com/blabla/bla.php" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://domain.com/blabla/bla.php</a> or more.' But if i have some like this : text = '<img src="http://img.com">' not to change this to : text = '<img src="<a href="http://img.com"" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://img.com"</a>>' i hope you got what i'm talking about, if not i can try to answer you another way, thanks.

Comment: Sure you need that monstrous regex? Give more detail, maybe a simple dom manipulation may be enough

Comment: @Raffaele that not so monstrous:) the problem is that i must check just what will be before http and that is a problem in js for now, for me. Is there construction that check was is before like (?< !\=\") that work in php and the problem is solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example above (including adding the ):

```
var text = 'something bla bla bla like this domain.com/blabla/bla.php or more. <img src="img.com" />'
```

This would work for you:

```
var newText = text.replace(/([^ ]*\.com\/[^ ]*)/g,'<a href="http://$1"; target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$1</a>');
```

And outputs:

```
something bla bla bla like this <a href="http://domain.com/blabla/bla.php"; target="_blank" rel="nofollow">domain.com/blabla/bla.php</a> or more. <a img src="img.com" />
```

Basically it recognizes the url by anything not a space in front of a `.com/` plus anything afterwards not a space. It won't grab the `<img src="img.com" />` as that's a `.com"`.

If you only have .com domains this will work, if you have .net, .org, etc, etc. then you'll have to add those as things to check.

Comment: That's is closer to my problem, thanks for your answer. But i need exactly checking a " symbol before http. I can explain this like this: if the url will on a new string your url can be corrupt by nhttp from /n. I don't try this right now, but i will.

Comment: `.replace(/(")?http/,'http');` will match with or without the `"`, `.replace(/[^"]http/,'http');` will match only if there is not a `"` in front. `.replace(/"http/,'http');` will match only if there is a `"`. If that still doesn't answer your question then you're going to have to give another example. The one you did give was solved.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest not to use a regex for this problem. Regex are not intended to be used with XML, so they eventually fail. You can use the following to accomplish an *autolink* functionality (jQuery):

```js
$('#text').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function(i, t){
    $(t).replaceWith(t.nodeValue.replace(/(http:\/\/[\S]+)/g,
       '<a href="$1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><b>$1</b></a>'));
});
```

This regex runs on text nodes, so you are guaranteed that you won't find any element like `<img>`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/S7t6Q/) is a live fiddle.

Note that this code won't work *as-is* with hierarchically complex elements, since `.contents()` only returns first-level children. You may want to use [a more complex solution](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/) if it suits.

However working with XML concepts (node, element, text node) **is the way** to solve your problem, so you'll have fast, working and robust code.

Comment: maybe you right, for now i take solution from first answer, but your answer interest for me too. Before replacement link to <a> tags, i make replacement links that end on .jpg or else and make an images from them.